# paypal adaptive payment sdk not responding today

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-rest-sdk

we have integrated php adaptivepayments-sdk-php-master few days back and its working properly 
but from yesterday it stops working and after some debugging i got to know that paypal services not responding and giving error of

Could not get any response
then i check for paypal developer console and its also giving error on api explorer

https://devtools-paypal.com/apiexplorer

any suggestions why this is happening and how to resolve this

[image]